# List of IEnumerables

Tags: vb.net

Please see the code below, which was written by someone else and works very well:

```
Public Function GetMembers(Optional ByVal sortExpression As String = "MemberId ASC") As List(Of Member) Implements IMemberDao.GetMembers
            Dim sql As String =
                " SELECT MemberId, Email, CompanyName, City, Country" &
                "   FROM [Member] ".OrderBy(sortExpression)

            Return db.Read(sql, Make).ToList()
        End Function

Public Iterator Function Read(Of T)(ByVal sql As String, ByVal make As Func(Of IDataReader, T), ParamArray ByVal parms() As Object) As IEnumerable(Of T)
            Using connection = CreateConnection()
                Using command = CreateCommand(sql, connection, parms)
                    Using reader = command.ExecuteReader()
                        Do While reader.Read()
                            Yield make(reader)
                        Loop
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        End Function

Private Shared Make As Func(Of IDataReader, Member) =
            Function(reader) _
                New Member() With {
                    .MemberId = Extensions.AsId(reader("MemberId")),
                    .Email = Extensions.AsString(reader("Email")),
                    .CompanyName = Extensions.AsString(reader("CompanyName")),
                    .City = Extensions.AsString(reader("City")),
                    .Country = Extensions.AsString(reader("Country"))
                }
```

I understand that Make is a delegate that populates the Member objects with values, but I do not understand how a list of Persons is returned by the Read function? (a list is returned and works very well).

Comment: it does this by using the yield. This is how iterators generally work. take a look here... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh156729.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it does this by the yield keyword. This is generally how it works when you are iterating over a collection. Take a look here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh156729.aspx

This should give you a good/simple understanding.

Comment: Thanks.  I understand that part.  I don't understand where the Member object is stored after Yield is called.  Can you elaborate on this please?

Comment: Sure. I'm sorry - what do you mean member object? do you mean the current item it is retrieving? The compiler will generate a class that implements IEnumerator, which has a MoveNext() function and a Current property. The class will have all the members required to store the state of the function between calls

Comment: Also, take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx - "When a yield return statement is reached in the iterator method, expression is returned, and the current location in code is retained. Execution is restarted from that location the next time that the iterator function is called."

Comment: The Member object is returned by the Make function in the code in my OP.  I do not understand where these objects are stored before they are converted into a list on the last line of: GetMembers().